Is there a non -remote way to debug push notifications with logs in React?
I'm having a little trouble with an APNS payload on my react-native app. I really just need to print out the JSON and some other info to help debug once the apps have been distributed internally (the only place you can test APNS, as far as I understand). I've tried copying JSON to the clipbboard, which works but only really lets me debug one thing at a time. Alerts also work but are limited in that they don't allow copying and pasting (atleast on iOS). I was wondering if there are any other easy ways to debug this sort of thing locally and easily that I'm not thinking of, other than clipboard, and alerts.
